# Keep Track of Time ssh'd into Work Machine for Time Card

Tags: ssh, login

How can I keep track of the time I spend ssh'd into a computer? Whenever I am working I ssh into my work server to start. It runs Ubuntu. It would be really nice if I could generate a list of when I was ssh'd into a computer for ease in filling out my timecard for work.

Note:
My home computer runs Ubuntu as well so a client side solution would work as well.

Comment: add a wrapper around ssh ?

Answer (score 3):

The **last** command can be used to view when a user session started and ended. In this example, john.doe made an SSH connection to the server on May 6 at 21:29, and disconnected at 21:51, meaning that john.doe was connected for 21 minutes.

```
[root@server1 ~]# last
john.doe  /dev/pts/0   client1.example.com  Sat May 6 21:29 - 21:51 (00:21)
```

The **/var/log/auth.log** or **/var/log/secure** file will also show SSH connections. In this example, john.doe made an SSH connection to the SSH server at 21:29:10 and disconnected at 21:51:09.

```
[root@server1 ~]# tail /var/log/secure
May  6  21:29:10 server1 sshd[15970]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session open for user john.doe by (uid=0)
. . .
May  6  21:51:09 server1 sshd[15970]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user john.doe
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's a bit too much work to find exact hours worked for a biweekly period every time I want to fill out my time card. I wrote a simple script to do the job for me and automatically back up data to GitHub:
https://github.com/sauhaardac/TimeKeep/blob/master/keeptime.sh

Comment: I totally agree that a script would be perfect for this.  I sure am glad you were able to make a script for this.